# React-native finally inpromise undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Finally code is undefined. How can we fix this?

```
 StorageService.getLoginResponseModel()
            .then(token => {
                if (token !== null) {
                    this.props.setLoginResponseModel(token);
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                const delay = 1000;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.goToNextPage();
                }, delay);
            });
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apaTO.png)

Comment: Could you share the full code snippet perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

`this.goToNextPage` doesn't exists after 1000.

You can just do

```
StorageService.getLoginResponseModel()
            .then(token => {
                if (token !== null) {
                    this.props.setLoginResponseModel(token);
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                const delay = 1000;
                setTimeout((cb) => {
                    cb();
                }, delay, this.goToNextPage);
            });
```